# pass string variable to 'type' in TypeOrmModuleOptions

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, typeorm, dotenv

I want to setup a database connection for my NestJs app using TypeORM. I have a config file which reads all values from the `.env` file

```
import { DotenvConfigOutput, config } from 'dotenv';

const envFound: DotenvConfigOutput = config();

if (!envFound) {
  throw new Error('.env file was not found.');
}

process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

export const DATABASE_TYPE: string = process.env.DATABASE_TYPE || 'postgres';
export const DATABASE_USERNAME: string = process.env.DATABASE_USERNAME || 'admin';
export const DATABASE_PASSWORD: string = process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD || 'myPW';
export const DATABASE_HOST: string = process.env.DATABASE_HOST || 'localhost';
export const DATABASE_PORT: number = Number(process.env.DATABASE_PORT) || 5432;
export const DATABASE_NAME: string = process.env.DATABASE_NAME || 'myDB';
export const DATABASE_SYNCHRONIZE: boolean = Boolean(process.env.DATABASE_SYNCHRONIZE) || true;
```

I am setting up the connection in the app.module, so on application startup.

```
import {
  DATABASE_TYPE,
  DATABASE_HOST,
  DATABASE_PORT,
  DATABASE_USERNAME,
  DATABASE_PASSWORD,
  DATABASE_NAME,
  DATABASE_SYNCHRONIZE,
} from './config';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: DATABASE_TYPE,
      host: DATABASE_HOST,
      port: DATABASE_PORT,
      username: DATABASE_USERNAME,
      password: DATABASE_PASSWORD,
      database: DATABASE_NAME,
      entities: [],
      synchronize: DATABASE_SYNCHRONIZE,
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Unfortunately I get this error at the `type` field

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"mysql" | "mariadb" |
>   "postgres" | "cockroachdb" | "sqlite" | "mssql" | "oracle" | "cordova"
>   | "nativescript" | "react-native" | "sqljs" | "mongodb" |
>   "aurora-data-api" | "expo"'.ts(2322) MysqlConnectionOptions.d.ts(12,
>   14): The expected type comes from property 'type' which is declared
>   here on type 'TypeOrmModuleOptions'

I don't want to pass in a hardcoded string like `'postgres'` because I want it to keep dynamic. I prefer Postgres but some customers use oracle databases and I have to support MSSQL too.

How can I fix that configuration problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert your database type to string like below:

```
   export const DATABASE_TYPE: any = String(process.env.DATABASE_TYPE) || 'postgres';
```

Comment: sorry no, that didn't work for me. The error still remains

Comment: please check my updated answer, I changed the type to `any` hope this helps

Comment: hm the error is gone :) I can remove the cast to a string, `any` seems to be enough

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me:

```
TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
  type: "sqlite" as any,
  host: "localhost",
  database: "./database/sqlite"
})
```

I spent a whole weekend trying to figure out this issue but got stumped.

Does anybody have a better solution or explanation?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue?

Comment: In my case making `type` value as **any** solves the problem, e.g. `type: 'postgres' as any`